# Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.hindsighttesting.behave:behave-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.3-104

Tags: java, maven, teamcity

Can anyone please help me in debugging/fixing this issue. When I run the project from my local it does so without any errors but when I try to do the same thing via Team City then I am getting below errors:

```
[17:59:45][Step 1/1] [ERROR] Plugin com.hindsighttesting.behave:behave-maven-plugin:1.0.3-104 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.hindsighttesting.behave:behave-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.3-104: Failure to find com.hindsighttesting.behave:hindsight-behave-parent:pom:1.0.3-104 in http://repo.hindsightsoftware.com/public-maven/com/hindsighttesting/behave/behave-maven-plugin/1.0.3-104/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of hindsighttesting.release has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[17:59:45][Step 1/1] [ERROR] 
[17:59:45][Step 1/1] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[17:59:45][Step 1/1] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[17:59:45][Step 1/1] [ERROR] 
[17:59:45][Step 1/1] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[17:59:45][Step 1/1] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
[17:59:45][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 1
```

Below is my POM file:

```xml
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>hindsighttesting.release</id>
        <name>Hindsight Software Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.hindsightsoftware.com/public-maven/com/hindsighttesting/behave/behave-maven-plugin/1.0.3-104/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.hindsighttesting.behave</groupId>
                <artifactId>behave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3-104</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server>https://behave.pro</server>
                    <projectKey>MASKED</projectKey>
                    <username>MASKED</username>
                    <password>MASKED</password>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>features</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        com.hindsighttesting.behave
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        behave-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.0.3-104,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>features</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute></execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.applitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>eyes-selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>smoke</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.hindsighttesting.behave</groupId>
                    <artifactId>behave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>%regex[.*Test.*]</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

can anyone please suggest as to what is going wrong when I am running this over Team City. I am a bit new to this so please excuse if its a stupid question

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the remote repository is missing the parent pom for that plugin ([behave-maven-plugin pom](http://repo.hindsightsoftware.com/public-maven/com/hindsighttesting/behave/behave-maven-plugin/1.0.3-104/behave-maven-plugin-1.0.3-104.pom)) and it can't be downloaded (check the [URL](http://repo.hindsightsoftware.com/public-maven/com/hindsighttesting/behave/hindsight-behave-parent/1.0.3-104/hindsight-behave-parent-1.0.3-104.pom) - it gives HTTP 404). Your local build works because it has that file cached in `$HOME/.m2/repository`.

Either the `http://repo.hindsightsoftware.com/public-maven` is missing the file, or the file is located in another repository which you need to add to your project's pom file.

You might workaround the problem by copying the `hindsight-behave-parent` maven files from your local maven repo (`$HOME/.m2/repository/com/hindsighttesting/behave/hindsight-behave-parent/1.0.3-104/`) to Team City's local maven repo.